# Can I connect a kotlin android app to a .net5 REST API

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, .net, kotlin

So I was thinking about learning about app development for android. I know you use kotlin however, I also want to start working with .NET and C# is there a possibility for my first app that I create a basic login and register form in the app using Kotlin and connect it to a .NET REST API? Is that a thing I am sure you are just using the URL for the API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, there are plenty of libraries that are able to help you with that, like Retrofit or Volley

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Using Retrofit, the Android app could be connected to the RESTful APIs that is available using the latest technology by Microsoft and the open source community; ASP.NET Core Web API 5.
A complete guide to do so:
http://codingsonata.com/a-complete-tutorial-to-connect-android-with-asp-net-core-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's a very common way to consume API for data processing purposes in android-based applications.

If you have learnt on how to consume API with Android Application (built using JAVA), it's pretty much the same.

if you have never used JAVA to create android applications that consume API, don't worry because the process you need to do is very simple, moreover there are already many collections of libraries that you can use for this purpose. You can try to look on several library such as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Let me show you a a simple example of using OkHttp to pass data from android to API. This simple example is quoted from this [article](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-form-parameters-kt-java)

```
  private val client = OkHttpClient()

  fun run() {
    val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
        .add("search", "Jurassic Park") /*The parameters*/
        .build()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php") /*API URL*/
        .post(formBody)
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
      if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

      println(response.body!!.string())
    }
  }
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you. If you need more assistance, don't hesitate to contact.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API, you use URL and model of your data.
I recommend Retrofit as a library for connecting to any API. A good example is [here](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial), check out this and I think you will be well prepared to write Kotlin code.

Firstly, you need to define retrofit client, with your URL:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://reqres.in")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

then you need to map your API as an interface, for example if you have an endpoint https://reqres.in/api/users? you must define them like this:

```
@GET("/api/users?")
Call<UserList> doGetUserList(@Query("page") String page);
```

For creating .NET Core API, especially with user registration you must check some of [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), I recommend to be familiar with [EF Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) ([other](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-identity-tutorial/)).